# The usage of [verb] + ing

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

What is the corrective sentence? And why?
And when I can  use [verb] + *ing*?

> My dog guards my room  not **letting** anyone inside.

Or

> My dog guards my room mustn't **let** any one inside.

Comment: Which do you think is correct and why?

Comment: Note that we don't say "What is the corrective sentence?" It should be "Which is the correct sentence?"

Comment: @AIQ Edit the question?

Comment: @JanDoggen By ving OP meant "verb + ing". Thing is, I edited another person's question like this before. But I was told (and correctly so) not to edit questions to a degree that may make the OP appear more fluent in the use of the language than they actually are. That is why I did not edit OP's question here. OP's *incorrect* and *unusual* phrasing of the question helps us understand the best way to write an answer for OP. Also, by commenting, I can get the OP to ask me why we say "correct" and not "corrective".

Comment: Your second sentence is actually ungrammatical. As a comparison, it should be something like: *My guard dog guards my room **and does** not let anyone inside.* (Note that I only replaced *must* with *does* because that's much closer to the meaning of the first sentence.)